# Restrict Postback on button client click event

Tags: asp.net

I am having an asp button in Update panel and a update progress attached with update panel.
I want restrict page postback on on button's client click event.

Comment: Do you won to restrict that on every button ? or only one one ? and after the first post back, or in generally restrict post back ?

Comment: I want to check some condition and if it fails erstrict the page from postback

Comment: Start vote and accept some answer to give some credits to the people that help you !.

Answer (score 0):

something that has worked for me:

... OnclientClick="yourfunction(); return false;"

Comment: i want to do write some condition if it fails returns false.I did that but not working.

Comment: The code in the "OnClientClick" attribute is handled as a js function. This function has to return false. So if "yourfunction" does any validation and returns a bool value, you have to return this in the OnClientClick 
OnClientClick="return yourfunction();"

Comment: I did that,It checks the condition and returns false,but also postback.

Comment: Hmm... so this seems to be a specific problem of your context. Sorry, I dont have enough knowledge about the update panel to help here...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a javascript function call that return true for continue and false for stop.

```
function AskFor()
{
    if(continue check)
     return true;
    else
     return false;
}
```

and on your button you add `OnClientClick="return AskFor();"`